# How to deal with changing folder names when your header guards and #includes use exact paths?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, include-path, coding-efficiency

I am coding in `C++` using the Visual Studio 2019 IDE.

I have followed the convention that every file `#include`s project files using the exact path. For example:

```
#include "ProjectName/FolderName2/HeaderName2.h"
#include "ProjectName/FolderName/src/HeaderName1.h"
```

I have also followed the convention of including the path in my `#ifndef` header guards:

```
#ifndef PROJECTNAME_FOLDERNAME_FILENAME_H
#define PROJECTNAME_FOLDERNAME_FILENAME_H

//...

#endif
```

This is the style suggest by the [Google Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Names_and_Order_of_Includes).

However, as I am coding, I may want to change folder names. For example, I may decide that `ProjectName` is not a correct description of the contents of the folder and that I should change the name to `ProjectName2`. This change, however, requires correcting header guards and each `#include` that uses `ProjectName` in the path description. This problem becomes significantly worse if I totally reorganize my code.

Are there (automatic) tools to  make this easier? Is `#include`ing the exact path (from the solution folder) the way to go?

Comment: "assume find and replace does not work here" thats a rather odd premise. Why does it not work? Finding the includes you have to fix is also trivial, try to compile and the compiler will tell you which includes you have to fix

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number because folder names often appear in other folder names, file names, namespaces, variable names, and comments.

Comment: you search for `#include "ProjectName/FolderName2/HeaderName2.h"`  and replace that with the correct include. I dont understand the issue.

Comment: if there are too many headers in a folder you could write a script, but it will still be search and replace

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number that is a good point. I have changed the original question to ask for "automatic" tools, which is what I was looking for. Something (presumably within the IDE) that fixes the ```#include```s when I change folder names.

Comment: note that both of your questions are considered offtopic (asking for tools / asking about good style)

Comment: I wouldn't use this style.   Simply `#include` the filename without the path information where possible, and modify the compilation options to specify include paths (path to search for header file).   Most compilers support that.    Worst case is if two distinct headers with the same name are on different paths - in that case, add minimal path information to the `#include` and specify include path as a containing directory. For example, if `header1` is in two distinct paths `FOO/a/header1` and `FOO/b/header1` then `#include "a/header1"` "and `"b/header1"` and specify `FOO` as the include path.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I believe your suggestion of "find and replace the entire ```#include```" is the best answer if there is no Visual Studio tool that does this automatically. I was originally thinking that I would just "find and replace" the folder name.

Comment: @Peter Is that portable across (common) operating systems (and not just compilers)? I don't know much about OSs.

Comment: Don't assume that because Google does something it's a good idea for you too.  They have problems you'll never have, and they have tools you'll never have too.

Comment: First, You don't need to follow strictly to a style guide, IF you have some problems, that are caused by them, AND there's no good solution either.

Secondly, as Mark also said, don't assume if Google created it, it's the standard to be followed, so you have to 'bypass' some problem that originate due to the choice

Comment: @mana   Depends on what you mean by a "common" operating system. It will usually work under windows and most unix variants, including some RTOS (with disk drivers) that support a hierarchical folder/file structure. Most compilers that target such systems support such approaches (option to specify include path, strings in `#include` support path specifiers). However, some (now) more obscure OS and their file systems do not support `'/'` as a path delimiter. Generally speaking, to be certain, you will need to test for a set of representative OS and the compilers that target them.